# Centrar não está a funcionar no ipad

Tags: html, css, ios

Estou a desenvolver uma apliacação android, mas estou a programar no eclipse no windows usando **HTML**, **JavaScript**, **CSS** e **JQuery**

Para testar o desenvolvimento da apliacação estava a usar uma extensão para o google chrome e às vezes também usava o **Chrome DevTools Overview** (F12) versão mobile.

O problema é que nesses dois sitios onde testava, o menu principal da apliacação estava bem centrada, tanto verticalmente como horizontalmente.
Neste momento, comecei a testar mesmo num device IOS e o menu aparece-me nada centrado.

Eu estava a usar este **CSS** que funcionava no chrome, mas não no device IOS:

```
.center{
    /** CENTRAR NO ECRA * */
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);   
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center; 
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="center">
                <img id="imgLogoLogin" src="img.png" alt="LOGO"
                    class="imgLogoCenter" width="250px" />
                <h1>Welcome</h1>
```

Alguma sugestão?

P.S Não tenho experiência nenhuma em IOS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provavelmente você precisa colocar também `-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` no seu CSS; a [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/transform) diz que `transform` funciona no Safari mas só com o prefixo.

Não tenho nenhum dispositivo iOS aqui, mas posso confirmar que com essa regra extra funciona no Safari desktop (e reciprocamente, que *sem* a regra o CSS não funciona); vide [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9n5Lo32r/).

Comment: Eu sei que não se deve fazer comentários deste genero. Mas muito Obrigado